# C# - Passing the object type in a method parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to pass a object type to a method. I'm doing this for my CRUDRepository that's inherited by others repositories, but i can't figure out how to know with type i'm handling.

For example:

```
    public PageOf<Entity> GetPageOfEntity(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
    // Here i need to work with the entity type to make calls to database  
    }
```

The **Entity** is a object that's inherited by other entities (user, products, etc) and this method is returning a paged result. I'm doing this to avoid creating a **GetPageOf** method for each entity that i've.

What's the proper way to pass to the method the object type that i want to deal in paged results?

**Edit:**

Here's a example of the Entity

```
     public abstract class Entity 
     {
     public virtual long Id { get; set; }
     public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
     }
```

And the user object:

```
     public class User : Entity
     {
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     }
```

As i'm trying to write a single class to handle some crud operations, i need to know in the method what object i'm using (but i'm trying to now create one method for each object type)

Thanks

Comment: little more code & details would help. Are you looking for passing a type? probably you can have an inbound argument of type `T` and then perhaps instantiate and do a GetType() on instance to check what type it is and build that typed pageOf and return.

Comment: I think what he's asking is how to resolve T back to a table in the data context..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955579/passing-just-a-type-as-a-parameter-in-c-sharp

Comment: Not really, i've asked this before. Check the dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the method generic:

```
public PageOf<TEntity> GetPageOfEntity<TEntity>(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    where TEntity : Entity
{
    Type entityType = typeof(TEntity);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll read about generic methods and classes to understand how this work.

Comment: Would you not also need an argument of type `TEntity` to get a page from?

Comment: @Phil: No, but you can not use type inference in that case. As long as you explicitly specify the type patameter, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I understand your question correctly, but can't you just use a generic parameter?

```
public PageOf<Entity> GetPageOfEntity<TEntity>(int pageNumber, int pageSize) 
    where TEntity : Entity
{
// Here i need to work with the entity type to make calls to database  
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but my English isn't perfect (i'm Portuguese) and sometimes i really can't express myself! But yes, generic parameter is what i need. Thanks ;)