# Passing just a type as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, types, methods, parameters

Hypothetically it'd be handy for me to do this:

```
foo.GetColumnValues(dm.mainColumn, int)
foo.GetColumnValues(dm.mainColumn, string)
```

where the GetColumns method will call a different method inside depending on the type passed.

Yes, I could do it as a boolean flag or similar, I just wondered if there was a way to perhaps pass this, and then ask:

typeof(arg[1]) or similar...

**I could also override the method, use generics, etc - I know there are  different ways to do this, I was just curious if this was possible.**

Comment: My thought exactly, depending on what foo actually is.  `foo.GetColumnValues<int>(dm.mainColumn)` may be the way to go.

Comment: As I said, I realise there are other ways to do this (boolean flag, generics, overriding the method) I just wondered if it was possible as a parameter.

Comment: @MarkMayo: I don't understand the question if you _"know that you could also override the method, use generics, etc and you know that there are different ways to do this, you were just curious if this was possible"_. So you know all this but you are curious if it is possible??

Comment: @TimSchmelter - in the form I describe.  i.e. passing it as the 2nd parameter.  As it turns out, Reed has kinda said what I was after - where you use (..., Type type).  That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Good question, upvoted, I see MS using Type as a parameter for built-in operators in VB.NET e.g. trycast, and have often wished I could do that myself in C#/VB - in the fashion you describe.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

There are two common approaches.  First, you can pass `System.Type`

```
object GetColumnValue(string columnName, Type type)
{
    // Here, you can check specific types, as needed:

    if (type == typeof(int)) { // ...
```

This would be called like: `int val = (int)GetColumnValue(columnName, typeof(int));`

The other option would be to use generics:

```
T GetColumnValue<T>(string columnName)
{
    // If you need the type, you can use typeof(T)...
```

This has the advantage of avoiding the boxing and providing some type safety, and would be called like:  `int val = GetColumnValue<int>(columnName);`

Comment: You can also do an extension method, public static T GetColumnValue<T>(this string columnName){...} then you can say foo.GetColumnValues<string>(dm.mainColumn)

Comment: But how do you define a method that has several arguments and one of them should be a generic? Since the generic is defined before the method  argument list, how do you know which one should be a generic then?

Comment: @BadmintonCat `T Foo<T,U>(string arg1, U arg2)` or similar

Comment: When using the first approach, is there a way to assign a default value to type?  (e.g. something like `object GetColumnValue(string columnName, Type type = object)`?  That doesn't quite seem to work for me but it would be useful to know.

Comment: typeof() is a function that takes in a type like int or char or some class name. eg Type c = typeof(char); .Net does not provide us the same privilege. GetColumnValue<T> as mentioned above seems to be the best one can do.

Answer (score 30):

`foo.GetColumnValues(dm.mainColumn, typeof(string))`

Alternatively, you could use a generic method:

```
public void GetColumnValues<T>(object mainColumn)
{
    GetColumnValues(mainColumn, typeof(T));
}
```

and you could then use it like:

```
foo.GetColumnValues<string>(dm.mainColumn);
```

Answer (score 17):

You can pass a type as an argument, but to do so you must use `typeof`:

```
foo.GetColumnValues(dm.mainColumn, typeof(int))
```

The method would need to accept a parameter with type `Type`.

---

> where the GetColumns method will call a different method inside depending on the type passed.

If you want this behaviour then you should not pass the type as an argument but instead use a type parameter.

```
foo.GetColumnValues<int>(dm.mainColumn)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
foo.GetColumnValues(dm.mainColumn, typeof(int));
foo.GetColumnValues(dm.mainColumn, typeof(string));
```

Or using generics:

```
foo.GetColumnValues<int>(dm.mainColumn);
foo.GetColumnValues<string>(dm.mainColumn);
```

Comment: I didn't dv you, but it was probably because you're showing how it would be called and didn't specify the function definition

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, just wrap it in `typeof()`

```
foo.GetColumnValues(typeof(int))

public void GetColumnValues(Type type)
{
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an argument of type Type - iow, pass typeof(int). You can also use generics for a (probably more efficient) approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use generic types !

```
  class DataExtraction<T>
{
    DateRangeReport dateRange;
    List<Predicate> predicates;
    List<string> cids;

    public DataExtraction( DateRangeReport dateRange,
                           List<Predicate> predicates,
                           List<string> cids)            

    {
        this.dateRange = dateRange;
        this.predicates = predicates;
        this.cids = cids;
    }
}
```

And call it like this :

```
  DataExtraction<AdPerformanceRow> extractor = new DataExtraction<AdPerformanceRow>(dates, predicates , cids);
```